# How to save really long text into database with angular and PHP

Tags: php, sql, angular

I have a project that needs to save a really long text. The problem that I have is that it **won't save** my input from my angular **if it is long text** but if it is a **short text,** **it will save**

this is my PHP Code:

```
<?php
//savepoem.php
require ("connect.php");

$postdata= file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);

$response = new stdClass();

$title = $request->title;
$content = real_escape_string($request->content);
$id = $request->id;
$desc = $request->desc;

$query = "INSERT INTO poem (Title, MemberID, Description, Content) 
VALUES('".$title."', '".$id."', '".$desc."', '".$content."')";

$result = $connect->query($query);

if($result){
    $response->msg = "Saved!";
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

everything is working fine, with the angular. I can save short text but not really long one. But if I save data directly into XAMPP shell it will save. This is my query in SQL that works in XAMPP shell,

```
MariaDB [bigproject]> insert into poem(Content) values('
    '> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse modi a placeat quibusdam cupiditate eius! Dolores rerum quidem a ipsa quam ipsum veniam, voluptates soluta enim? Numquam voluptates provident quas odio ipsam, laboriosam autem praesentium. Unde omnis labore ab mollitia animi consequuntur asperiores magnam necessitatibus. Accusantium debitis enim commodi explicabo, molestias nulla beatae iste porro reiciendis aut, iusto deleniti maxime laborum possimus ut repellat? Deserunt quidem inventore nihil beatae quisquam? Qui autem possimus sit tenetur maxime, deleniti facere suscipit aut molestiae. Quae molestiae quibusdam, consequuntur doloribus non excepturi repudiandae illum. Cumque, labore fuga ipsum distinctio tempora incidunt pariatur sint! Eos!'
    -> );
Query OK, 1 row affected, 3 warnings (0.004 sec)
```

Note: the 3 warnings is nothing to worry about I just left it null for a moment.

This is my table for this

```
MariaDB [bigproject]> desc poem;
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| PoemID      | int(10)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| MemberID    | int(10)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| TempID      | int(10)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Title       | text     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Content     | longtext | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Description | text     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.015 sec)
```

Also, I tried to change the type into longtext and make the Collation to utf-8 but it doesn't work.
**UPDATE:**
this is the error that I received in my console, still won't save.
[image]

Comment: "I can save short text but not really long one" - what happens instead?

Comment: Also, be warned that you rcode is highly vulnerable to SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements if you want to aovid them

Comment: What do you mean by to highly vulnerable to SQL injection? Im still a beginner to SQL.

Comment: If I tried to save a long text long like lorem100, it won't save if it is saved using PHP and Angular. But if i save it directly using xampp shell it will.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is there any error message given? Usually, such code either works, or throws an error. It won't fail silently

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply, I hope you see this. Bu I updated my question and those are the error that I saw on my console

Comment: Is there a limitation on your Webserver on the POST size? Try to print out the content of the request before inserting into the db

Comment: i think it doesn't have limit when it comes to post are u talking about the $_POST? i don't use that in my project. Thank you :)

Comment: That does not look like a PHP error after all. How does that response look like? Please inspect the raw response